# Change default python version from 2.6.6 to 2.7 and also configure django

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I am new to linux (Ubuntu) and python (Django). By default there is python 2.6.6 in my linux, I installed python 2.7. In the command prompt when I type python it goes to python 2.6.6, I want to change my default python to 2.7.

Comment: Fix by unlink? :)  Ok fine, if that doesn’t work there’s always clri!

Comment: I would suggest asking a new question for configuring the web project.  The chances of you finding someone that can help with ALL of those topics will be few and far between.  Have you looked into SO questions that deal with setting each of these components individually?  You might get better results for mysql and appache on serverfault's stack exchange.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu might have a Python2.7 package. If so, install that then use that to create a [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) and put Django inside that.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use [pythonbrew](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew) which can install and switch between multi Python interpreters in your $HOME without touch your system directories.

BTW, when install python, use the command

```
pythonbrew install --no-test 2.7.2
```

to skip unitest could speed up the installation a lot.

Comment: +1 I use homebrew on the Mac, which achieves the same thing as pythonbrew.  Love the concept and workflow when using it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to modify your path and make sure the path to Python 2.7 is before Python 2.6.  This is what I have done on my Mac to achieve similar things.

**EDIT**
I agree with Noufal Ibrahim in the fact about using [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).  I would also suggest looking into [virutalenv wrapper](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper).  However, you still might have trouble using Python 2.7 is your path is not configured correctly, using an Ubuntu package for the install *should* take care of the path for you.  Otherwise to install virtualenv from the bash shell, you can do something along the lines.

```
$ path/to/python27/python easy_install virutalenv
$ pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

I believe when installing virtualenv, it will set your PATH for you.  You can confirm this by doing:

```
$which python
```

This should now show Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the links, I tell ya. Look at the links. Check the inode's link count for python2.5, python2.6, python2.7, python3.2, etc. Notice those are greater than one.

Just hunt down the duped link to "python", fix by unlink, and relink it. It may be a real link, or just a sym link. unlink with extreme prejudice.

```
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  admin  12392 Oct  4  2009 /opt/local/bin/python2.5*
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  12392 Jul 23 17:14 /opt/local/bin/python2.6*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  72 Nov  7  2008 /usr/bin/python@ -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin  41476 Jul  3  2010 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7*
-rwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  2072216 Jul 27 19:34 /usr/local/bin/python3.2*
```